# What lysis buffer recipe is good for just breaking the cell membrane?

Tags: cell-biology, enzymes, cell-membrane

I am interested in the decellularization of plant leaves(more specifically maple) and thus need a lysis buffer. I want the buffer to only break the cell wall and cell membrane and I want to observe the proteins in the cytoplasm so the buffer can't be too strong as to deactivate the proteins/enzymes in the cytoplasm(I don't care about the nucleus). I looked at RIPA, SDS, and NP-40 but they are all too strong and can damage the proteins. Is it possible to only use salt in a buffer solution without any detergent and if not, could you please recommend me a lysis buffer solution? For more clarity, I am mostly interested in looking at hexokinase. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Look for lysis buffer kits labeled for creating nuclear extracts. There are generally two buffers: one to lyse the cell membrane, after which the lysate is spun down and washed, then a second buffer to lyse the nuclear membrane. I don't have time at the moment, but I'll try to find a reference for you later.

Comment: I just realized that you're talking about plant samples, where you also need to lyse the cell wall. Have you considered mechanical lysis, either with a mortar and pestle or sonication?

Comment: If I were you I would look into dounce homogenizers, along with the use of a cellulase to break down the cell wall.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have considered mechanical lysis but I am working with small samples so it isn't as efficient as chemical lysis. Mechanical lysis can also create localized heating which can denature some proteins so if possible I would use chemical lysis over mechanical. Using a cellulose is a good idea but I still need to break the cell membrane with chemical lysis

Comment: Also, can alcohol also break the cell wall like cellulase?

Comment: Centrifuge. Use a diluted salt solution and centrifuge the sample to separate the cell wall.